# What does the term mid-supply refer to?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

Here is an example from a data-sheet of an [opamp](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM321-D.PDF):

> (At TA = +25°C, RL = 10 k connected to **mid-supply**, VCM = VOUT =
>   mid-supply, unless otherwise noted. Boldface limits apply over the
>   specified temperature range, TA = –40°C to 85°C, guaranteed by
>   characterization and/or design.)

Does mid-supply mean ground for dual-supplies?
And what does it mean for a single supply opamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dual supplies that are symmetric, eg +/- 10v, mid-supply means ground.

When the supply pins of an op-amp are not symmetric about ground, for instance 0v and +5v for a single supply amp, or -4v and +12v for some arbitrary dual supply, then mid-supply means, well, mid-supply, +2.5v in the first example, +4v in the second.

A common way to get an 'RL of 10k connected to mid supply' is to use two 20k resistors, one connected to the -ve supply, one connected to the +ve supply.

Comment: "use two 20k resistors, one connected to the -ve supply, one connected to the +ve supply." And the opamp output is connected to the middle connection of the the 20k resistors?

Comment: The mid point of the two resistors is the '10k load to mid-supply'. So yes, that should be connected to whatever you want to load.